# Add Multiple Handlers to 1 Address

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I am looking to set many handlers to the address of one of my methods. For example, once all my handlers are set it would be the same as writing the following code:

```
Private Sub ModificationsMade(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Analyse_tbCurrentDescription.TextChanged, Analyse_tbNewDescription.TextChanged, Analyse_tbTimeTests.TextChanged, Analyse_tbTimeInstallation.TextChanged, Analyse_tbTimeMaintenance.TextChanged, Analyse_nupCurrentAmount.ValueChanged, Analyse_nupNewAmount.ValueChanged, Analyse_cbCurrentTime.SelectedIndexChanged, Analyse_cbCurrentOccurence.SelectedIndexChanged, Analyse_cbNewTime.SelectedIndexChanged, Analyse_cbProgrammer.SelectedIndexChanged, Analyse_dgvTasks.CellValueChanged
    Analyse_Saved = False
End Sub
```

My `Analyse_Saved` variable is used in my listview item changed. If it is true than I don't need to save anything because it was already saved. If it is false though, a modification was made and I should prompt the user to save his information before he changes items.

As you can see, I have many controls which are handled by their respective events in a case of a modification. This enables me to notify my user if an item has been modified in the form.

The only problem is, when the user changes item in a listview, all those events are triggered because the textboxes, comboboxes, and so on get inputed with information. Because of this, I would Add and Remove my handlers accordingly.

Unfortunately, I don't want to add a line for each control to be handled such as:

```
AddHandler Analyse_tbCurrentDescription.TextChanged, AddressOf ModificationsMade
```

My question is, what is the simplest way to add multiple handlers to 1 address destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either will have to add a line for each control:

```
AddHandler Analyse_tbCurrentDescription.TextChanged, AddressOf ModificationsMade
```

Or loop through your controls (if you find a criteria to group them into a loop, such as a common parent), and do the same line in a loop.

However, what you should be doing instead is separating a business logic layer from the UI. Then you don't have this problem.

**EDIT:** Regarding your update, if your business logic object is a DataRow, it has versions, so you can compare the current version against an old one. Using `RowState` may not appropriate in cases when user changes A -> B and then B -> A. In such example you should really not register a change, although `RowState` will end up being `Modified`. Using `Analyse_Saved = False` will always register a change, similar to `RowState` approach.

Comment: I'll loop through each control and group them accordingly ... I'll look into the business logic layer, seems interesting. Not sure why my question was downvoted ... I put a lot of information :s Thank you!

Comment: @Alex: My guess is that you did not describe your end goal well. `Analyse_Saved = False` does not tell me much, for example. Usually when you better describe your end goal, rather than the approach you are taking, people can recommend a completely different way of solving your issue, if applicable. Such as a business logic layer change I suggested above. My assumption was that you are trying to perform some validation on a data form and are looking to have a centralized location for processing.

Comment: I have often thought that downvotes should require a comment.

Comment: @dbasnett: This has been a common problem on SO, unfortunately. I upvoted your comment, so more people could see it. Wish it was actually **required** by the system.

Comment: @dbasnett I know... I think the same. I upvoted it as well, anyway...  @Neolisk I provided more insight on why I use the variable `Analyse_Saved`

Comment: @Alex: Thanks. BTW, I added more information regarding your edit - see my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative solution can be declare 2 functions.
One function add the handlers to every controls (i.e. AddHandlers()).
The other function remove the handler from every controls (i.e. RemoveHandlers())

So you have only to call RemoveHandlers(), do your things and then AddHandlers().

Answer (score 1):

> The only problem is, when the user changes item in a listview, all
>   those events are triggered because the textboxes, comboboxes, and so
>   on get inputed with information. Because of this, I would Add and
>   Remove my handlers accordingly.

This issue, and the related one of preventing triggering events on form load etc I've generally handled by a boolean called eg EventsArmed which is only set to true when I want the events to do stuff; then checking that boolean (If EventsArmed then . . ) as part of the 'form is dirty' code.

Comment: Yeah my colleague suggested that. Infact, I was going to do that first but I wanted to try something new. Thanks! :)